# get in type mismatch with the .find in a IF condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, find

I am getting a type mismatch error for the following code. Why?

```
If (Range("C:C").Find(What:=last_received, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)) is Nothing Then
        tic = 1
    End If
```

Also I have created a Range variable and set it to noting and used the below code, but still I get the same error:

```
If (Range("C:C").Find(What:=last_received, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)) = rr Then
        tic = 1
    End If
```

Comment: sorry, but what are you trying to do?

Comment: Your first bit of code works for me. No errors. What is the value of `last_received`?

Comment: @mehow i am checking if a particular ticket number is available in a sheet in column C if the value is not available then i have to change the ticket number, what my code basically dose is that the range.find give me the range in which the particular value is available if the value is not there then it will return Nothing

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett the reason the first code works for u is because you will not have the ticket number available in your sheet (last_received will have a ticket number from another sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
   Dim c As Range, lr&
   lr = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For Each c In Range("C1:C" & lr)
       If c like last_received Then 
            tic = 1
       End if
   Next
```

Answer (score 0):

(posted on behalf of the OP, murugan_kotheesan)

thanks to mehow. the below is the final working code

```
    Sheets("Extract -prev").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C3"        'taking last received ticket
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    last_received = ActiveCell.Value
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calc").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="Yesterday_last_received"
    ActiveSheet.Paste

'----------changing last received ticket if it is not available in todays ticket

    Sheets("Extract").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Worksheets("Extract").AutoFilterMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter

   lr = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For Each rr In Range("C1:C" & lr)
       If rr Like last_received Then
            tic = 0
       End If
   Next

    Do While (tic <> 0)
        Sheets("Extract -prev").Select
        Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        last_received = ActiveCell.Value

        Sheets("Extract").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Worksheets("Extract").AutoFilterMode = False
        Selection.AutoFilter

        lr = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each rr In Range("C1:C" & lr)
        If rr Like last_received Then
        tic = 0
        End If
        Next
    Loop
```